# Why does DataCache client behave this way?

Tags: c#, appfabric-cache

I have a cache instance running on Windows Azure.  I'm connecting to it from my web application and getting intermittent exceptions with the following message:

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure.
>   Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are
>   unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For
>   on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions.
>   Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client
>   account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed
>   through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the
>   server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size
>   sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying
>   to communicate with the server:
>   net.tcp://myserver.cache.windows.net:22234.

I've been able to duplicate the problem with this snippet in LinqPad

```
var config = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration
{
    AutoDiscoverProperty = new DataCacheAutoDiscoverProperty(true, "myserver.cache.windows.net"),
    SecurityProperties = new DataCacheSecurity("key", false)
};
var factory = new DataCacheFactory(config);
var client = factory.GetDefaultCache();
//client.Put("foo", "bar");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(o => {
        var i1 = (int)o;
        try
        {
            client.Get("foo").Dump();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.Message.Dump();
        }
    }, i);
}
```

If I run this snippet as-is, spawning more than about 50 threads, I get the error.  If I uncomment the initial Put(), I can run it with 10,000 threads.  I make sure the entry is in the cache regardless before I run this.  I've tried using pessimistic locking and it does not seem to have any effect.  I've used the latest client DLLs from NuGet.  I've tried scaling the cache up to 1GB with no other usage besides this snippet.

Since my requests in my web app are coming in on different threads, I believe this reasonably simulates what's happening in my app.  And I'm definitely getting the same exception in both cases.  Can anyone suggest a way to avoid this exception?  Does it have to do with the initial Put() happening on the same thread as the constructor?  That seems unlikely but it's the only thing I can do in this test scenario to eliminate the exception.